# Input field changing the value of the data already submitted by the form?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

After the data is submitted, then added to the array, then being display in the table. If i make a change in the input text field it is being diretly reflected to the table.

like this
[image: the input fields in here are directly changing the data value that has been added using the form, see the same values in last three rows]

HTML

```
<body ng-app="crud">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="sub()">
      <label for="name">name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="myForm.name" />
      <br><br>
      <label for="contact">contact</label>
      <input type="text" name="contact" ng-model="myForm.contact" />
      <input type="submit" value="sumit" ng-click="sub" />
    </form>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.contact}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="edit(x)">Edit!</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
 var app = angular.module("crud", []);

 app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = [{
     name: "ankur",
     contact: 987898
   }, {
     name: "santosh",
     contact: 987678
   }, {
     name: "tanvi",
     contact: 98789877
   }];
   $scope.count = 0;
   $scope.myForm = {};
   $scope.myForm.contact = 0;
   $scope.myForm.name = "";
   $scope.sub = function(myForm) {
     $scope.data.push($scope.myForm);
   };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Angularjs is object oriented.
Instead of pushing the same object into the array, take a copy and push. That'll do the favor for you.

```
 $scope.data.push(angular.copy($scope.myForm));
```

**Another way**

```
  <form>
      <label for="name">name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="myForm.name" />
      <br><br>
      <label for="contact">contact</label>
      <input type="text" name="contact" ng-model="myForm.contact" />
      <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="sub(myForm)" />
    </form>
```

**in Js**

```
$scope.sub = function(myForm) {
     $scope.data.push(myForm);
   };
```

Comment: Is there any other way that i should be adding the form values. It works just doesn't seem to be the best way :(

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the best method. What will be the another way you will do to push an item in array.

Comment: I am trying to develop a simple CRUD with angular. I think doing copy might complicate things for later.

Comment: Copy won't give complicate things. Or you can create a fresh new object with the updated values and then can insert. For update, delete, get the specific object from the lists and then update and delete. use $filter to get the specific object.

Comment: Thanks, But the example that you have added in the answer have the same problem.

Comment: If you say about the problem that you will face in future, then it will be easy for use to give a solution.